# Software identification of a DIY (guitarist) CAD application

Tags: software, cad

I know there is a reasonably popular tag for component identification, however I have a question about software identification.

Before I used KiCad (when started with electronics), I used for a while a very simplistic 'CAD' program for perfboard layouts. However, I reinstalled my PC since, and I cannot find the name of the application anymore. I need it because I want to open the (complete) layout I made for an old project to see if I can 'revive' it.

I only have a screenshot and some info about it... it was meant mostly for guitarists, and it was (afaik) only possible to make some kind of perfboard layouts). The internal components where very basic and some guitarist specific ones.

The application extension is `.diy` and the name also had DIY in it (I think), but DIY is not the most easiest keyword to search for on Google.

I would like to know the name (or link) of this application, so I can install it (at least temporarily) to see my old design.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened again (just after searching for at least half an hour), I find it within 5 minutes after posting the question.

Anyway I found the application:

It's called DIY Layout Creator.

Link:

http://diy-fever.com/software/diylc/

(In case you think it's advertisement: if you are serious about electronics, most are here, use a 'real' CAD application like KiCad, Altium etc).

Comment: Sometimes one must expose ones ignorance publicly before inspiration (or Google Fu) can strike.  This sort of thing happens to me all the time.

Comment: Maybe next time I should just write it, but not post it, but of course than it will not work.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work for me.  I must actually expose my inability to the English-speaking world.  Then I can figure it out on my own.